# Browser support for array.includes and alternatives

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

I looked it up and found this regarding finding a substring in a larger string in an array. [Array.Prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
if (t.title.includes(searchString))
```

My `t` is part of a `$.each` that's iterating through a larger array of objects (each objects got a buttload of info, from strings, dates and such). `searchString` is whatever the user typed in a box. All this is a simple search function for a list I have on the page.

This works just fine in Chrome. But Firefox and IE are turning up errors stating

```
TypeError: currentTicket.title.includes is not a function
```

So I either put up a warning sign that my app only works on Chrome or I handcraft a find function? Weird thing is the doc page from MDN I posted states that only Firefox supports the `array.includes`, strangely enough it's only Chrome that runs it.

Comment: So basically a function that doesn't work in any browser except *maybe* the newest versions of Chrome and Firefox and you're wondering why it's not working? This function should be easy to polyfill btw, it's right there in the link you posted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution is posted in the question !

Comment: BTW you're not using `Array.prototype.includes`, but rather `String.prototype.includes`. You might just as well use the common `indexOf` method of doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Tried utilizing `Array.prototype.some` ?

Comment: @adeneo It's not that black and white. I just added the relevant documentation towards my question, but I don't know quite well what it means. I'm not sure what a polyfil is or how to use it (refer to my comment on the other answer). As for using indexof, I'm getting the same error from Firefox and IE

Comment: What exactly is `currentTicket.title`, and what are you trying to match. If you show what you're trying to do, there's probably a better cross-browser way to do it.

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @Thaenor: mark the highest upvoted answer as accepted, i'm pretty sure that it also solved your problem.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Instead of using an API that is currently marked as "experimental" consider using a more broadly supported method, such as `Array.prototype.indexOf()` (which is also supported by IE).

Instead of `t.title.includes(string)` you could use `t.title.indexOf(string) >= 0`

You can also use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get a new array of strings that meet a certain criteria, as in the example below.

```js
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"];
document.getElementById("input").onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = arrayContainsString(arr,this.value);
}
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);

function arrayContainsString(array, string) {
  var newArr = array.filter(function(el) {
    return el.indexOf(string) >= 0;
  });
  return newArr.length > 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<br/>
<div>array contains text:<span id="output" />
</div>
<div id="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

As the MDN article you linked to says, Firefox only supports `.includes` in nightly builds, other browsers didn't support it at all *at the time the article was last updated* (Chrome may have been updated to support it at a later time). If you want to support all browsers, you can use the polyfill outlined in the same article:

```
if (![].includes) {
  Array.prototype.includes = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex*/ ) {
    'use strict';
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = parseInt(O.length) || 0;
    if (len === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    var n = parseInt(arguments[1]) || 0;
    var k;
    if (n >= 0) {
      k = n;
    } else {
      k = len + n;
      if (k < 0) {k = 0;}
    }
    var currentElement;
    while (k < len) {
      currentElement = O[k];
      if (searchElement === currentElement ||
         (searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement)) {
        return true;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return false;
  };
}
```

However, it sounds like your problem has a better solution, but it's hard to tell without any specifics.

Comment: What exactly is a Polyfill and how do I apply it on my js? Sorry, I tried Googling this one but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: [The first result from Google](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill) covers the subject rather well: a polyfill is a piece of code that ensures a browser has certain functionality available (like `Array.prototype.includes`) regardless of whether it's supported natively. You'll want to include it somewhere on your page before you want to use the method, so most likely as early as possible.

Comment: I tried copying that piece of code but it doesn't do anything. Does it act like a normal function or...

Comment: If the above doesn't address your issue then it's likely your target object isn't an array to begin with. Impossible to tell without more code.