# JavaScript: check if string contains '.' (a full-stop)

Tags: javascript, string, forms, search

I am trying to search a string to see if it contains a period "."
I loaded the value of an input field into a variable then ran a javascript string search() method on that variable.

```
var _email = document.getElementById(Input).value;
var contains_dot = _email.search(".");
```

The contains_dot variable should return -1 if a period is not found in the string OR a number representing the position of the match.

Sadly... the variable 'contains_dot' returns nothing but 0 every time.
Am i doing something wrong?  ..is there a better way?

Please note:

```
contains_dot = _email.indexOf(".");
```

Does NOT work for this question as it returns 0 no matter what the input.

Comment: `.indexOf('.')`

Comment: @AnthonySottile I also tried .indexOf('.') and the result was the same... so that didn't work.

Comment: Please confirm that `_email` contains what you expect before trying to see if it contains a `.` ...

Comment: @AnthonySottile has the right answer. Do a `console.log(_email)` before calling `_email.indexOf('.')` to make sure your input string is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Why does that happen?

The reason why `_email.search(".");` returns `0` every time is because [String.prototype.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) takes a regular expression as its input.

`.` means match any character in regex. In other words, if your input has at least one character of anything, it will return 0.

---

### The Solution

If you simply change it to `_email.search(/\./);`, it will work exactly as you intended.

Browser support: All known browsers

If you don't care about browser support, you may also use `_email.includes('.');` as mentioned by Cade Brown.

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for reference. Browser support: Only Chrome 41+ and Firefox 40+ (recent browsers)

Comment: Using a regex seems like an overkill for this. `indexOf` is better in that case.

Comment: Thanks, your snippet of code did exactly what i wanted.
And i also learnt something about 'matching any character in regex'.

Comment: @ReallyNiceCode Great :) You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) for more info on the `.` in JS RegEx. If all you need is to find the dot though, I'd recommend `indexOf` or `includes` as others have mentioned. They should be more efficient in performance. `indexOf` is also compatible with all known browsers.

Comment: @jonathanGB Agreed. I wanted to point out why the original code didn't work and also offer a quick fix based on the OP's original reasoning.

Comment: I understand, you explained it well. But you should edit your answer to mention `indexOf` and why it should be used over `search` here, and possibly over `includes` if compatibility is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `string.includes(".")`
This returns `true` or `false`

If you want a `1` or `-1`, simply use:

`(x.includes(".")) ? 1 : -1`

EDIT:

After searching a bit more, I ran across:
[Browser support for array.include and alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461565/browser-support-for-array-include-and-alternatives)
and others.

**Use `x.indexOf(".") > -1`**

Comment: Thanks, string.includes(".") did the job for me.
I will do some reading on the linked post also.

Answer (score 0):

[`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) interprets its parameter as a regular expression, so you need to escape the `.` with a  (double) backslash as it will otherwise match any character:

```
var contains_dot = _email.search("\\.");
```

But because you don't need a regular expression, it would be simpler to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var contains_dot = _email.indexOf(".");
```

Comment: 'var contains_dot = _email.search("\\.");'  ...actually did the job, thanks.
  _email.indexOf("."); was tried before and all it returned was 0

Comment: Hmm...there must be something else going on here as this is exactly what `indexOf` does. e.g. `'foobar'.indexOf('.')` returns -1.